# Box Collision some boxes are not colliding (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, collision, box, direction

So I wrote this code to check for the collision between boxes.

```
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0 ; j < boxes.length; j++) {
        if (i != j) {
            if (boxes[i].posX + 50 >= boxes[j].posX
                && boxes[i].posX <= boxes[j].posX + 50
                && boxes[i].posY + 50 >= boxes[j].posY
                && boxes[i].posY <= boxes[j].posY + 50
                ) {
                console.log("box" + i + "collide with box" + j);
                boxes[i].movePosX *= -1;
                boxes[i].movePosY *= -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works for 2 to 3 boxes, but when I keep 4 or more boxes some of the boxes collide but doesnt change its direction.
can anyone help me debug this?.
Also can anyone teach me process of debugging as how I can detect the problem.
New to Javascript.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < boxes.length; j++) {
        if (i != j) {
            if (!(boxes[i].posX + 50 <= boxes[j].posX
                || boxes[i].posX >=  boxes[j].posX + 50
                || boxes[i].posY + 50 <= boxes[j].posY
                || boxes[i].posY >= boxes[j].posY + 50
            )) {
                console.log("box" + i + "collide with box" + j);
                boxes[i].movePosX *= -1;
                boxes[i].movePosY *= -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I usesed this function from: http://7pi.azurewebsites.net/surir.de/collisions/

```
function cc_rect_rect(r1, r2) {
    return !(r1.pos.x >= r2.pos2.x || r1.pos2.x <= r2.pos.x || r1.pos.y >= r2.pos2.y || r1.pos2.y <= r2.pos.y);
}
```